# Fill page with body and stick footer to bottom with flex (Tailwindcss, Nextjs)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to use flex-grow to make the body section fill the screen and have the nav stick to the bottom, but I can't figure out which elements to apply them to. Can anyone point me to which element it should be on?

I tried making the div above the nav in _app.js flex with flex-col then applied flex-grow to the body section of categories/[slug].js, but no luck.

```js
import Head from "next/head";
    import Link from "next/link";

    import Skeleton from "react-loading-skeleton";

    import { CURSORY_ARTICLES_BY_CATEGORY_QUERY } from "../../queries/articles";

    import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
    import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

    const Main = () => {
        const router = useRouter()
        const { slug } = router.query;
        
        const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(CURSORY_ARTICLES_BY_CATEGORY_QUERY, {
            variables: { category: slug }
        });

    return (
        <div>
        <Head>
            <link
                rel="preload"
                href='../public/fonts/Apple.ttf'
                as="font"
                crossOrigin=""
                />
        </Head>
        <div className="max-w-full flex container bg-gray-terminal bg-image justify-around">  
            <ul className="flex flex-col font-apple">
            {   
                loading ? <Skeleton count={6} width={512} height={256}></Skeleton> : 
                error ? <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p> :
                data.articles.map(
                        (article) => {
                            return (
                                <Link href={`/articles/${article.slug}`}>
                                    <li key={article.slug} className="rounded gird grid-cols-4 justify-between cursor-pointer my-8 mx-2 md:mx-4 lg:mx-8 text-green-terminal hover:text-white border-4 border-green-terminal hover:border-white shadow-2xl bg-gray-terminal">
                                        <h1 className="mx-4 py-4 sm:py-2 w-1/3 col-span-1 font-apple">{article.title}</h1>
                                        <p className="mx-4 text-sm py-4 sm:py-2 w-2/3 col-span-3 font-apple">{article.description}</p>
                                    </li>
                                </Link>
                            );
                        }
                ) 
            }
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
    }

    export default function SelectedCategory() {
        return (
            <Main />
        )
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React from "react";

import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import client from "../lib/apollo";

import Nav from "../components/nav";
import Footer from "../components/footer";

import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return ( 
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <Nav />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer className="max-w-full container flex flex-col items-center bg-black font-apple">
            <Link href="https://twitter.com/Unenunciate">
                <svg className="my-4 cursor-pointer text-green-terminal fill-current hover:text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 4.557c-.883.392-1.832.656-2.828.775 1.017-.609 1.798-1.574 2.165-2.724-.951.564-2.005.974-3.127 1.195-.897-.957-2.178-1.555-3.594-1.555-3.179 0-5.515 2.966-4.797 6.045-4.091-.205-7.719-2.165-10.148-5.144-1.29 2.213-.669 5.108 1.523 6.574-.806-.026-1.566-.247-2.229-.616-.054 2.281 1.581 4.415 3.949 4.89-.693.188-1.452.232-2.224.084.626 1.956 2.444 3.379 4.6 3.419-2.07 1.623-4.678 2.348-7.29 2.04 2.179 1.397 4.768 2.212 7.548 2.212 9.142 0 14.307-7.721 13.995-14.646.962-.695 1.797-1.562 2.457-2.549z"/></svg>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/contact">
                <div className="tracking-wider text-md mb-4 text-green-terminal hover:text-white border-green-terminal hover:border-white hover:shadow-lg">
                    Contact
                </div>
            </Link>
            <div className="text-green-terminal text-sm mb-2">
               Copyright Ⓒ 2021
            </div>
        </footer>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import CATEGORIES_QUERY from "../queries/categories";

import Link from 'next/link';
import Skeleton from "react-loading-skeleton";

import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

export default function Nav() {
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(CATEGORIES_QUERY, {
        variables: { slug: "categories" }
    });

    return (
        <div className="bg-black max-w sticky">
            <div>
                <nav className="flex justify-between container mx-auto py-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li className="group flex flex-row mx-2 text-green-terminal group-hover:text-white border-b-4 border-radius border-green-terminal hover:border-white hover:shadow-lg">
                    
                            <Link href="/">
                                <div className="flex flex-row cursor-pointer">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="group-hover:text-white text-green-terminal fill-current h-5 w-5 -translate-y-2 icon  " viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#fff">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 5a2 2 0 012-2h12a2 2 0 012 2v10a2 2 0 01-2 2H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V5zm3.293 1.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l3 3a1 1 0 010 1.414l-3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L7.586 10 5.293 7.707a1 1 0 010-1.414zM11 12a1 1 0 100 2h3a1 1 0 100-2h-3z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                    </svg>
                                    <span className="group-hover:text-white font-apple tracking-widest">
                                        Uenunciate
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                    <div className="flex justify-between">
                        <ul className="flex flex-wrap mx-2 md:mx-4 lg:mx-8">
                                {   
                                    loading ? <Skeleton count={2} width={12} height={12}></Skeleton>: 
                                    error ? <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p> :
                                    data.categories.map(
                                            (category) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <li key={category.slug} className="mx-2 md:mx-4 lg:mx-8 font-apple tracking-widest text-green-terminal hover:text-white border-b-4 border-green-terminal hover:border-white hover:shadow-lg ">
                                                        <Link href={`/categories/${category.slug}`}>
                                                            {category.name}
                                                        </Link>
                                                    </li>
                                                );
                                            }
                                    ) 
                                }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to only apply [align-items: stretch;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) ([tw class:  items-stretch](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items)) on the main content element.

However, you might need to go a bit deeper and style your body, :root (html) and #__next elements. Here is a general [SASS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support) with [Next tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs#include-tailwind-in-your-css) version.

```
:root,
body,
#__next {
  @apply flex flex-col flex-1;
  @apply h-auto min-h-full w-screen max-w-full;
  @apply m-0 p-0;
  @apply overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden;
}
```

[Here is a codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-nash-w1yjb?file) - it's not using tailwind classes because I couldn't get it to work with next 10 in codesandbox. It's using vanilla CSS but you can get the idea.

Just some advice:

Set your svg fill to "currentColor", it will allow you to easily color them with text color classes.

Your next/links need to be wrapped in an "a" [per the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) if you are adding anything other than text or adding additonal props.

Exenal links should't use next/link and they should use rel="nofollow noreferrer" to enhance security for your users.

The example also includes the above advice.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those suggestions for the body worked; the footer one did, but it isn't quite what I meant. /n This tutorial is what I was trying to do, but can't seem to apply them properly: /n https://dev.to/nehalahmadkhan/how-to-make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-web-page-3i14

Comment: Specifically, I was trying to do what the poster said and what the first comment on that post suggested with flex-grow

Comment: Check out the example I posted

Comment: I tried the example tailwind you had there, but that didn't work. I see the logic behind it working and I am not understanding why it isn't. From what I think setting min-h-full should fix the issue like you suggested but it didn't change anything. Thanks for the other advice, too.